# Supersymmetric Nonrenormalization Theorems

Tags: quantum-field-theory, supersymmetry, research-level, renormalization

I'm looking for approaches to nonrenormalization theorems in supersymmetric QFT which are as much as possible mathematical, elegant and involve few heavy straightforward computations

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/450880/2451

Answer (score 11):

One approach is that of Seiberg

http://arXiv.org/abs/hep-ph/9309335

which is also expanded upon a little bit (and explained in a slightly different way) by Weinberg

http://arXiv.org/abs/hep-th/9803099

The old point of view is based on explicit supergraph computations

http://inspirehep.net/record/141168?ln=en

The disadvantage of the supergraphs approach is that it is bound to be valid only in perturbation theory. The advantage of it is that it is extremely rigorous and transparent. You said you were looking for a mathematically solid and elegant approach, so I would probably recommend this one. But the intuitive methods of Seiberg proved much more powerful because of their non-perturbative validity and simplicity.

Comment: Thx! Is there an exposition of the supergraph approach which is freely available online?

Comment: Sure 

http://arXiv.org/abs/hep-th/0108200

But it is advisable to acquire Wess&Bagger, where there is an introduction to the subject as well.